# Is it possible to prove inf. with archimedes axiom for that inequality $ \frac{1+3n}{3+n^3} < \epsilon $?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Is it possible to proof with archimedes axiom that better infimum does not exist for that inequality?

$$ \frac{1+3n}{3+n^3} < \epsilon , n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\} $$

I need to transform that expression so that n is alone on one side and "all" $\epsilon$ are on the other. If the inequality shows that n is greater, then the proof is complete. However I don't know if that's possible in that case.

The problem is that n exists in 2 separate places with 2 separate powers. When it's just one variable it is easy to do the proof.

Comment: You ask for "better infimum". What infimum do you now have that you want to know if there's a better (smaller) infimum?

Comment: The infimum is $0$ and I know that there is no better infimum. But I know that from a sketch of function + limit arithmetic. Now I have to prooh that formally with archimedes' axiom.

Comment: Hint: Supposing that $n$ must be a natural number, we can say $\dfrac {1+3n}{3+n^3} < \dfrac {4n}{n^3}$

Comment: If you put $n=-1$ in left side, result is $-1.$ So infimum is not zero unless some restriction is placed on $n.$

Comment: n is a natural number greater than $0$, I forgot to mention

Comment: With your restriction from your last comment, the comment of @player3236 can be used with Archemedes axiom.

Comment: Wow, so when I prove that some value is the inf or sup to any set of values, I can always put some value in the inequality between my element a (element of set of values) and the other side of the inequality (with supposed inf or sup and $\epsilon$)?

Comment: theboyboy---I think it works for inf zero... provided can get "some value between" as something boundable via Archemedes.